# Active Directory Integration with Grails

Tags: grails, active-directory, shiro, active-directory-group

My web application created using Grails 2.4.4 with shiro:1.2.1 and it's working fine. In my application I've created one user with limited permissions called xyzUser.

Now I've a domain, username, password of the active directory. And my requirement is to allow the request from the same and bypass login page and provide all the access of xyzUser.

For that I've tried

> org.grails.plugins:ldap:0.8.2

plugins and add following configuration in config.groovy (https://grails.org/plugin/ldap)

```
ldap {
    directories {
        directory1 {
            url = "ldap://demo.myDomain.in"
            base = "ou=demo,dc=myDomain.in"
            userDn = "uid=Username,ou=demo,dc=myDomain.in"
            password = "Password"
            searchControls {
                countLimit = 40
                timeLimit = 600
                searchScope = "subtree"
            }
        }
    }

    typemappings = [
            my.app.MyTypeMappings
    ]
}
```

Now I can't understand that what to do next to fulfill my requirements...

Comment: I have no experience of groovy, but from what I can see, in the current example scenario you've an incorrect configuration of base and userDN(there might be more mistakes). Please get them checked with system-admin team. Once your configuration is fine, the user from AD can authenticate using their credentials.

Comment: I've checked in document it's correct (https://grails.org/plugin/ldap)

Comment: You didn't get my point. See, if I assume the URL is `ldap://domain.in`, then accordingly, the base would be *`ou=example,dc=domain,dc=in`*, the userDN would be `uid=Username,ou=example,dc=domain,dc=in`. Please understand the dependency of URL on other types, specially on the DC parts.

Comment: Got it, Change the same.